# How to allow vendors to manage TFS work items from outside corporate network

Tags: tfs, ldap

We use LDAP security for our TFS internally, but we have a few vendors who we would like to give web access to for viewing, creating or updating work items.

Can anyone recommend a good approach to accomplish this without moving our TFS host to an external location?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to open your TFS externally and create user accounts for the vendors.

A couple of references to expose your TFS to the internet:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668967.aspx
- http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/2010/05/01/microsoft-team-foundation-server-2010-and-external-access-fqdn/